# How to rotate something upwards based on mouse position in Java

Tags: java, mousemotionlistener

Good afternoon guys, I'm trying to rotate an polygon based on my mouse position, but I can't figure out how to rotate the polygon upwards based on my mouse y. I'm using MouseMotionListener. I've tried to do this until now:

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m){
             int yantes= m.getY();
             while (true){
                int y = m.getY();
                repaint();
                if (y - yantes > 0){
                  rotation++;
                  if (rotation > 360) rotation = 0; 
                  repaint();
                  break;    
                } else {
                    rotation--;
                    if (rotation < 0) rotation = 359; 
                    repaint();
                    break;  
                }
            }

        }
```

The yantes variable tries to calculate the y before the move, and y the y in after the movement.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if I could visualize what is happening. This would require that you provide an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example), which would allow me to compile this and rotate a simple polygon. As it is, it would be more difficult than I'm willing to do now in order to create a program that I could compile.

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for the attention, I uploaded my code in my GitHub page. You go on [Java code](https://github.com/arthurprioli/Criacao-de-Games-em-Java/blob/master/capitulo04/RotatePolygon.java). And the HTML is in [HTML](https://github.com/arthurprioli/Criacao-de-Games-em-Java/blob/master/capitulo04/RotatePolygon.html). You can use appletviewer, to see what is happening.

Comment: Java applets were deprecated since Java 9 in 2017 and removed from Java SE 11 (18.9), released in September 2018

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I am using a book that used Java 6, so it focuses on applets. But there are a lot of concepts of game dev, that is why I`m using it.

Answer (score 0):

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256562/how-to-rotate-something-upwards-based-on-mouse-position-in-java#comment108378061_61256562), you wrote:

> I am using a book that used Java 6

Are you referring to the book [*Beginning Java SE 6 Game Programming, Third Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B7RE82Q) ?

A java *applet* is a [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) and so is a [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), so you can achieve the same results by extending class `JPanel` rather than extending `Applet`. That means you can write a regular java application without the need for HTML or a Web browser.

Instead of overriding method `paint()` in `Applet`, you need to override method `paintComponent()` in class `JPanel`.

The below code demonstrates rotating a square by moving the mouse. It rotates the square around the center point of the square. When you place the mouse inside the `JPanel` and move it to the left, the square rotates anti-clockwise. When you move the mouse to the right, the square rotates clockwise. If you move the mouse up and down, i.e. parallel to the y-axis, the square does not rotate.

```java
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Rotating extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener {
    private int  theta;
    private int  lastX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private BasicStroke  stroke;
    private JFrame  frame;

    /**
     * Creates and returns instance of this class.
     */
    public Rotating() {
        stroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    }
/* Start 'MouseMotionListener' interface methods. */
    @Override // javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mousEvnt) {
        int newX = mousEvnt.getX();
        if (lastX == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            lastX = newX;
        }
        if (newX < lastX) {
            theta--;
            if (theta < 0) {
                theta = 359;
            }
        }
        else if (newX > lastX) {
            theta++;
            if (theta > 360) {
                theta = 0;
            }
        }
        lastX = newX;
        repaint();
    }
/* End 'MouseMotionListener' interface methods. */
/* Start 'Runnable' interface methods. */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }
/* End 'Runnable' interface methods. */
    @Override // javax.swing.JComponent
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(theta), 300, 300);
            g2d.setStroke(stroke);
            g2d.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        }
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Rotating");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Rotating());
    }
}
```

Note that when overriding method `paintComponent()` you nearly always need to first call method `paintComponent()` in the super class.